# how to enable the "show Touch On highlight" in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uibutton

Anyone can help me to enable the "show Touch on Highlight" property of  uibutton. I know we can check in the xib editor. But it is not working. Do we have any other option to enable that 
?

Comment: ButtonOBj.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;

Comment: Atlast I have fixed this, my button was in the background. I have just brought the button to the front i.e In the interface builder  Editor -> Arrangement -> send to front

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either use

```
yourButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

or use

```
yourButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

to change the image of button when the button is highlighted.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use both? When I use `showTouchWhenHighlighted` then `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` won't work anymore.